# Tomcat 5.5 IP redirect to Hostname

Tags: ip, tomcat, hostname, redirection

How to setup Tomcat if my user entered "http://192.168.0.1:8080/axis2", it will redirect to http://servername.com:8080/axis2? I want the url/hostname appeared on user's web browser instead of ip address.

Any help will be appreciated.Currently i am using Tomcat 5.5 to host my system.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a DNS ( local http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-xp-tips/edit-hosts-file/ or public ) . For more information regarding DNS please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System .

Comment: mind to explain step by step?